# Python, trying to generate dictionary inside comprehensive list

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

If I want to generate dictionary from list of words using comprehension and ternary inside, I encounter some issues and need help.

Dictionary should be generated without extra module importing, using word length as key, and word as value.
Here's my problem the most simplified:

```
l=['hdd', 'fdd', 'monitor', 'mouse', 'motherboard']

d={}

for w in l :
    if len(w) in d  : d[ len(w) ].append( w )
    else            : d[ len(w) ] = [ w ]

# and dictionary inside list is OK:
print [d]
>>>[{11: ['motherboard'], 3: ['hdd', 'fdd'], 5: ['mouse'], 7: ['monitor']}]
```

Then tried to make it comprehensive :

```
d={}
print [ d[ len(w) ].append( w ) if len(w) in d else d.setdefault( len(w), [w] ) for w in l ]
>>>[['hdd', 'fdd'], None, ['monitor'], ['mouse'], ['motherboard']]
```

...which does not work. Any help?

Comment: It's because your list will consist of the return values of your expressions.  Try `print d[3].append(123)` in the prompt and see.  The actual dictionary `d` is fine.

Comment: Upvote for let me see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine, but you are not looking at the right thing : do not print what the list comprehension returns.
It gives you the list of the `d[ len(w) ].append( w )` yield by the list comprehension but what you are interested in is just `d`.

```
l=['hdd', 'fdd', 'monitor', 'mouse', 'motherboard']

d={}
[ d[ len(w) ].append( w ) if len(w) in d else d.setdefault( len(w), [w] ) for w in l ]
print d
>>> {11: ['motherboard'], 3: ['hdd', 'fdd'], 5: ['mouse'], 7: ['monitor']}
```

Which seems to be what you expect.

Comment: Heh! In such occasions comprehension is just syntax :)